# Is there a word/term for a pair of words/terms that have the same synonym for their different definitions?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I'm wondering if there's a word to describe this relationship––a word with multiple definitions and with the same synonym for their multiple definitions.

For example, *bring up* and *raise*:

- It is difficult to bring up children in that town.
- It is difficult to raise children in that town.
- The speaker brings up an important concern.
- The speaker raises an important concern.

Comment: They are still synonyms—just for different (multiple) things. This is no different than *box* being a synonym for *carton* despite the fact that *box* has multiple senses.

Comment: @JasonBassford I meant that the synonyms for the words were the same for their different definitions.
For example, while box and carton are synonyms with the following definition: 
"a container with a flat base and sides, typically square or rectangular and having a lid" box and carton are not synonyms when using another definition for box: an area on a page that is to be filled in or that is set off by a border.
but bring up and raise are synonyms for the multiple definitions of raise as used in the example sentences above